# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name "user's db name" is not bound in this Context?

Tags: java, jndi

I am working on project that has following error. i referred internet. followed it what they said. but it is still giving the error. it wasted my full day. please suggest me.

server.xml:

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
    <Context docBase="targetapp" path="/targetapp" reloadable="true"/>
    <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
   <Resource driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" maxActive="1" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10" name="jdbc/test" password="root" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" username="root"/>
  </GlobalNamingResources>
```

error log:

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name test is not bound in this
>   Context   at
>   org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:770)    at
>   org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:140)    at
>   org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:781)    at
>   org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)    at
>   com.cubs.util.DbUtil.getDataSource(DbUtil.java:61)    at
>   com.cubs.util.DbUtil.getConnection(DbUtil.java:37)    at
>   com.cubs.cubscore.UsersDb.getDepartmentId(UsersDb.java:3803)  at
>   com.cubs.cubscore.UsersDb.getMedicalDeptId(UsersDb.java:3823)     at
>   com.cubs.cubscore.Users.getMedicalDepartmentId(Users.java:1423)   at
>   com.cubs.cubscore.Users.getAllMedicalAdministrators(Users.java:1447)
>     at org.apache.jsp.dashboard_jsp._jspService(dashboard_jsp.java:82)
>     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:386)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 06 Sep 2017 22:14:30 FATAL
>   DbUtil - javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name nascocrm is not
>   bound in this Context java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: This question does not provide any context, please provide information on what you tried so far, what are you trying to achieve, etc, or it will be nearly impossible for someone to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this file META-INF folder then The error won't come back.

context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/myapp" docBase="myapp"
   crossContext="true" reloadable="true" debug="1">
          <Resource driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
          maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" 
          name="jdbc/test" 
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" username="root" password="root" />

</Context>
```

Comment: Yes it will, if you keep using 'test'. This resource has a different name.